# opam fails trying to install lwt looking for pthreads

Tags: ocaml, opam

On a Ubuntu Trusty VM, I've installed opam (version 1.2.0) from the ppa recommended by Real World Ocaml set up docs.

When running

```
opam install lwt
```

the build fails, and examing the .out file shows:

```
testing for pthread: ........................... unavailable
not checking for glib

The following recquired C libraries are missing: pthread.
```

I have the Ubuntu package libpthread-stubs0-dev installed.  What do I need to install to let the install succeed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://github.com/realworldocaml/book/wiki/Installation-Instructions:

> 14.04 [Trusty] comes with recent versions of ocaml and opam. No PPA needed.

The instructions worked for me in a Trusty VM.

Also, make sure you have the **aspcud** package installed. Otherwise, opam often chooses the wrong versions of packages, and I've seen this error once in that case.

Comment: Thanks - was just wondering if there was some way of getting it working with opam 1.2